# issues in access in kotlin when using "when" statement

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

Hey this is pretty straight forward question.

This is the code:

```
    when(img.id) {
         is R.drawable.blank1 -> img.setImageResource(R.drawable.chip10)
        R.drawable.chip10 -> img.setImageResource(R.drawable.chip20)
        R.drawable.chip20 -> img.setImageResource(R.drawable.chip50)
        R.drawable.chip50 -> img.setImageResource(R.drawable.chip100)
        R.drawable.chip100 -> img.setImageResource(R.drawable.blank1)

        else ->
            throw IllegalArgumentException("Undefined button clicked")
    }
```

As seen in the picture all statements excluding the first are OK, in the first statment when the "is" appears I have unresolved reference to `R.drawable.blank1` why is that? is this an IDE bug?[image]

***EDIT***
I am asking regarding the error itself, if it was a type miss-match I would understand but why is the "is" prevents from resolving the reference?

Comment: `is` means you are checking if `img.id` is a member of the class listed after `is`. But since you don't have a class named there, just some instance of something, it cannot be compiled.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I see, just remove `is` in the first line after `when` statement.

So replace your code with (remove **is**)

```
when(img.id) {
        R.drawable.blank1 -> img.setImageResource(R.drawable.chip10)
        R.drawable.chip10 -> img.setImageResource(R.drawable.chip20)
        R.drawable.chip20 -> img.setImageResource(R.drawable.chip50)
        R.drawable.chip50 -> img.setImageResource(R.drawable.chip100)
        R.drawable.chip100 -> img.setImageResource(R.drawable.blank1)

        else ->
            throw IllegalArgumentException("Undefined button clicked")
    }
```

Comment: please explain are you saying that an is statement "blocks" me from getting into R. folders? if so why is that?

Comment: I've added example